# Does .NET have soft references?

Tags: .net, soft-references

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why doesn't .NET have a SoftReference as well as a WeakReference, like Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/324633/why-doesnt-net-have-a-softreference-as-well-as-a-weakreference-like-java)

Java has several types of references, two of these are [Weak](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/ref/WeakReference.html) and [Soft](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/ref/SoftReference.html).  I know that .NET has [Weak](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404247.aspx) references but does it have Soft ones too?

(Soft references are stronger than Weak ones in that they will try to keep an object alive even when no strong references exist.  They do release however when memory is tight.)

Comment: Basically the same question: [Why doesn't .NET have a SoftReference as well as a WeakReference, like Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/324633/why-doesnt-net-have-a-softreference-as-well-as-a-weakreference-like-java)

Answer (score 0):

No, it doesn't.